# SSTP VPN not encrypt packets?

Tags: networking, vpn, encryption, routing, wireshark

I had installed SSTP VPN server (windows server 2012) and then tryied to check whether my traffic is encrypted or not. I had used wireshark and got strange result: packets to all servers, but my RADIUS are encrypted, but to RADIUS they are not encrypted. I had checked my route table. Results are here:
[image: Route print]

I suppose that traffic to my RADIUS (172.16.1.2) is going through 172.16.1.2 route, but i can't understand why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was to wildly speculate, then I would guess that `172.16.1.2` also happens to be the IP address of your VPN server.  The link between this system and the VPN server can't transit the VPN, so a static route gets added when the VPN starts, and the default gateway is adjusted to point at the VPN.

This is why most people strongly suggest making a VPN server be the only service provided by a computer/device.

Comment: It seems to be the reason, i have RADIUS and VPN in one server. Thanks!